# C++, вопрос про атомарность

Tags: c++, многопоточность, atomic

Я не могу найти ответы на следующие вопросы:

1. Существует мнение, что если атомарные объекты имеют неверное выравнивание, то такие объекты теряют свою атомарность. Объяснений, почему это происходит, я не нашел. И даже не нашел объяснений, всегда ли это происходит, или только в том случае, если атомарный объект оказывается на границе двух кешлиний.
2. Существует мнение, что несинхронизованное изменение неатомарной переменной из разных потоков может приводить не только к нарушению порядка изменения этой переменной, но и к тому, что в переменной окажется *сломанное* значение. Например, один поток запишет одну половину значения, а другой - другую. Это объяснение кажется правдоподобным, но лишь в отрыве от специфики синхронизации данных между ядрами/процессорами. Насколько мне известно, *обычно* мельчайшей единицей синхронизации между ядрами/процессорами является кэшлиния, размер которой, как правило, составляет 64 байта. Поэтому, мне не ясно, как многобайтовая переменная может *сломаться*, если она целиком попадает в одну кэшлинию.

Я буду очень благодарен за любую информацию по этим двум вопросам. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: по 2 пункту - чисто в теории возьмём `long long` на 32-битной платформе. он состоит из 2 машинных слов, поэтому чисто в теории можно записать 1 слово один потоком, а второе слово - другим. Аналогично `long double`. Если брать не стандартный тип, а например структуру, то всё ещё очевиднее. По 1 пункту - вопрос сложный, но я слышал что тогда чтение происходит весьма криво. Ряд ассемблерных инструкций требуют выравнивание, поэтому если объект не выровнен то добавляются специальные инструкции (и тут можно потерять атомарность). Кстати из-за этого ещё и баги бывают.

Comment: Если говорить про С++, то 1. атомарные объекты имеют правильное выравнивание 2. состояние гонки является неопределенным поведением

Comment: *"если атомарные объекты имеют неверное выравнивание"* А ну-ка покажите, как создать невыровненный объект в стандартном C++, не получив UB. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я понимаю, что создание невыровненных объектов - это UB. Просто интересно, как именно это ломает атомарные объекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++ есть стандарт, и там написано что

1) все объекты должны быть выравнены, иначе поведение не определено
2) при гонках поведение не определено

Если вы используете невыравненные переменные, или если у вас гонки, читайте документацию процессора.

Например, в доках Интела, том 3A, глава 8.1.1 Guaranteed Atomic Operations:

> The P6 family processors (and newer processors since) guarantee that the following additional memory operation will always be carried out atomically:
>   • Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache line.

У других процессоров может быть другое поведение. Также оптимизатор С++ опирается на стандарт, а не на архитектуру процессора, и может выкинуть ваш нестандартный код.